# String interpreted as a bool?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to find the length of a password before going on with my program but python keeps telling me that I'm instead trying to compute the length of a bool:

```
input_name = input('\nWe need you name: ')

if input_name in members:

    while True:
        input_pass = input('Input your password: ')
        if len(input_pass == 0):
            print("Can't be null!")
            continue
        else: break 

else:

    print('Sorry, your not part of the League.')
    bin_1 = input('Would you like to join?')
```

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "hoteltranselvania.py", line 25, in <module>
if len(input_pass == 0):
TypeError: object of type 'bool' has no len()
```

Comment: It should be `len(input_pass) == 0`. `input == 0` is a comparison resulting in either True/False. That is why `len(input_pass == 0)`is throwing the error

Comment: Thanks! Can't believe I didn't see that.

Comment: You can just write `if not input_pass:` to check for an empty string anyway...

Comment: Thanks for that too, much easier.